# MVC 5 Prompt for Windows Authentication Only Once

Tags: iis, model-view-controller

On a MVC 5 application, I have this in the Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="<list of authorized users>" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The application correctly authenticates users from the specified list, but my issue is that it asks every single time that the page is refreshed, or navigated to. I want it to ask once and then remember the user as they navigate between pages on the application. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, storing memebr in for windows authentication is not related with the IIS setting. This is related with the Browser setting. I guess you may disable the auto submission of windows credentials by browsers.

For IE or Chrome(Chrome browser uses system settings which are managed using Internet Explorer)：

Notice: You should add the url in the intranet as below image shows:

[image]

1.Navigate through Menu bar to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

2.Select Local Intranet and Click on "Custom Level" button

3.Scroll to bottom of the window to User Authentication section, select "automatic logon only in intranet zone"

[image]

For firefox:

1.Start Firefox

2.In the address bar, type about:config. At the prompt that warns to proceed with caution, agree to continue.

3.After the config page loads, in the filter box type: network.automatic. You should see a search result of network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

4.Modify network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris by double-clicking the row, and then enter https://your_SecureAuth_FQDN.com; Multiple sites can be added by comma delimiting them, as in this example: https://your_SecureAuth_FQDN.com, https://www.replacewithyourintranetsite.com

5.Click "OK" and close Firefox