# ASP .NET Core 6 with Windows authentification - don't show user login prompt dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I've created an ASP .NET Core 6 Web App with Windows authentification from a template
[image]
and I assume that current Windows user's credentials to be obtained automatically.

Application is working that way while debugging in Visual Studio 2022 (in Debug)
[image]
But when being deployed on a server (Windows Server 2012 R2+IIS 8.5) in a local network -
user login prompt dialog appears
[image]

How to get rid of this dialog and force my application to get current Windows user's credentials autimatically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A site hosted at localhost is trusted by the browser, so that user credentials are sent directly. If you want `https://xxx.xxx.ru` to be trusted by your browser, learn the browser settings. There is nothing you need to change on IIS.

Comment: As far as I know, the IE browser's security settings contains the "automatic logon only in intranet zone",  this could cause this issue. Moore details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029358/mvc-5-prompt-for-windows-authentication-only-once/55038404#55038404).

Answer (score 0):

This is a system setting on the client. On Windows, find it in Control Panel => Internet Options => Security => Local Intranet => Sites => Advanced. Make sure your domain name or IP address is in this list.

If this is not your problem, there's a long discussion of the server configuration for Windows authentication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828132/1585345)

[image]