# Windows authentication in ASP.net core: browser asks for credentials even on the same machine/domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm developing an `ASP.net Core 6` web api where I want to use windows authentication (NTLM) to authenticate calls.

So, following the MS documentation, I've installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` Nuget package. Then, I've configured my startup class like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddNegotiate();
    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

and in then in the Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

Finally, I've decorated the controller actions I want to protect like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("test")]
public string Test()
{
    return User.Identity.Name;
}
```

I've then tried to navigate to that endpoint with my browser, running on the same machine as the webapp and reaching it via localhost. This is when the problem happens, with two strange behaviors:

- The browser asks for credentials (classic username/password popup), even though I'm running client and server on the same machine
- If I click "cancel" without providing any credentials the controller action executes anyway and the user IS AUTHENTICATED

So, the automatic authentication is working correctly "under the hood", the only problem is that the browser for some reason still asks for credentials even though it doesn't need them.

Why is this happening? I've tried with Chrome, Edge and FF and they all behave like this.

Comment: Have you use your browsers dev tools to see what network requests are being performed?

Answer (score 0):

The automatic authentication is management by the IE Internet Options(win10) or Internet Options(win11).

If you are using the win11, you could refer to below steps to modify the login opinion.

1. search for "Internet Options"
2. "Security" tab
3. Click on the "Trusted sites" zone
4. Click on the "Sites" button
5. Insert the required website into the zone (if it is not https, then you must first deselect "Require verification ...." and after insertion mark again
6. Restart Edge

If you are using the win10, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038404/7609093) to modify the settings.